# Using order by clause with skip and take fails

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, asp.net-core-2.1, azure-sql-server

I am using EF Core for my .NET Core 2.1 project to interact with Azure SQL Server.

I have query which fetches around 1.5L rows by joining multiple tables. It's taking a long time to return the result and it is getting timed out (more than 30 seconds). So I am going with pagination using skip and take.

So my final call looks like

```
query.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

This call works absolutely fine and give the expected results.

But when I add order by clause to this query:

```
query.OrderBy(sortField)
     .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList()
```

Below is the generated SQL

```
SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[CreatedById], [p].[CreatedOn], [p].[CurrencyId], [p].[CustomerId], [p].[DataMigrationLogId], [p].[FollowUp], [p].[IsActive], [p].[ProjectName], [p].[PlantCode], [p].[ShipToDistanceFromPlant], [p].[StatusId], 
[p].[UpdatedById], [p].[UpdatedOn], [p.DataMigrationLog].[Id], [p.DataMigrationLog].[CreatedOn], [p.DataMigrationLog].[GeneratedOn], [p.DataMigrationLog].[HasEdsBid], [p.DataMigrationLog].[HasMbiBid], [p.DataMigrationLog].[Log], 
[p.DataMigrationLog].[RequestXml], [p.DataMigrationLog].[Status], [p.DataMigrationLog].[Xq1ProjectId], [p.UpdatedBy].[Id], [p.UpdatedBy].[CellPhone], [p.UpdatedBy].[CreatedOn], [p.UpdatedBy].[Discriminator], [p.UpdatedBy].[Email], 
[p.UpdatedBy].[FirstName], [p.UpdatedBy].[HasAccessToDoors], [p.UpdatedBy].[HasAccessToWindows], [p.UpdatedBy].[IsActive], [p.UpdatedBy].[LastName], [p.UpdatedBy].[Prefix], [p.UpdatedBy].[RecentProjectId], [p.UpdatedBy].[UpdatedOn], 
[p.UpdatedBy].[WorkPhone], [p.UpdatedBy].[XQ1LoginName], [p.UpdatedBy].[IsSuperAdmin], [p.UpdatedBy].[HasAccessToRestrictedReports], [p.UpdatedBy].[HasEdsProgramAndDealerPriceAccess], [p.UpdatedBy].[IsIss], 
[p.UpdatedBy].[ProjectVisibilityId], [p.UpdatedBy].[CustomerId], [p.UpdatedBy].[IsApiUser], [p.CreatedBy].[Id], [p.CreatedBy].[CellPhone], [p.CreatedBy].[CreatedOn], [p.CreatedBy].[Discriminator], [p.CreatedBy].[Email],
[p.CreatedBy].[FirstName], [p.CreatedBy].[HasAccessToDoors], [p.CreatedBy].[HasAccessToWindows], [p.CreatedBy].[IsActive], [p.CreatedBy].[LastName], [p.CreatedBy].[Prefix], [p.CreatedBy].[RecentProjectId], [p.CreatedBy].[UpdatedOn],
[p.CreatedBy].[WorkPhone], [p.CreatedBy].[XQ1LoginName], [p.CreatedBy].[IsSuperAdmin], [p.CreatedBy].[HasAccessToRestrictedReports], [p.CreatedBy].[HasEdsProgramAndDealerPriceAccess], [p.CreatedBy].[IsIss],
[p.CreatedBy].[ProjectVisibilityId], [p.CreatedBy].[CustomerId], [p.CreatedBy].[IsApiUser], [p.Status].[Id], [p.Status].[Code], [p.Status].[Name], [p.Customer].[Id], [p.Customer].[AxCustomerNumber], [p.Customer].[CreatedById],
[p.Customer].[CreatedOn], [p.Customer].[CreditTermId], [p.Customer].[CurrencyId], [p.Customer].[CustomerTypeId], [p.Customer].[DefaultPricing], [p.Customer].[FabricSystemFreight], [p.Customer].[IsActive], [p.Customer].[IsSpecialFreight],
[p.Customer].[LocalityRepId], [p.Customer].[MinFreightCharge], [p.Customer].[CompanyName], [p.Customer].[Notes], [p.Customer].[PrimaryBusinessId], [p.Customer].[ProgramAccountId], [p.Customer].[Prospect], 
[p.Customer].[ShippingDollarsThreshold], [p.Customer].[ShippingMilesThreshold], [p.Customer].[SpecialNote], [p.Customer].[SpecialPlantInstruction], [p.Customer].[UpdatedById], [p.Customer].[UpdatedOn], 
[p.Customer].[Xq1ProgGroupName], [p.Customer].[Xq1SrNo], [p.Customer].[XqCustomerNumber], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[Id], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[AxCustomerNumber], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[CreatedById], 
[p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[CreatedOn], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[CreditTermId], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[CurrencyId], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[CustomerTypeId], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[DefaultPricing],
[p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[FabricSystemFreight], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[IsActive], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[IsSpecialFreight], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[LocalityRepId], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[MinFreightCharge],
[p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[CompanyName], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[Notes], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[PrimaryBusinessId], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[ProgramAccountId], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[Prospect], 
[p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[ShippingDollarsThreshold], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[ShippingMilesThreshold], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[SpecialNote], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[SpecialPlantInstruction],
[p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[UpdatedById], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[UpdatedOn], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[Xq1ProgGroupName], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[Xq1SrNo], [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[XqCustomerNumber],
[p.Customer.CustomerType].[Id], [p.Customer.CustomerType].[Code], [p.Customer.CustomerType].[Name]
FROM [Projects] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN [DataMigrationLogs] AS [p.DataMigrationLog] ON [p].[DataMigrationLogId] = [p.DataMigrationLog].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Security].[XQUsers] AS [p.UpdatedBy] ON [p].[UpdatedById] = [p.UpdatedBy].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Security].[XQUsers] AS [p.CreatedBy] ON [p].[CreatedById] = [p.CreatedBy].[Id]
INNER JOIN [ProjectStatuses] AS [p.Status] ON [p].[StatusId] = [p.Status].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Customers] AS [p.Customer] ON [p].[CustomerId] = [p.Customer].[Id]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [p.Customer.LocalityRep].*
    FROM [Security].[XQUsers] AS [p.Customer.LocalityRep]
    WHERE [p.Customer.LocalityRep].[Discriminator] = N'SALES_SP'
) AS [t] ON [p.Customer].[LocalityRepId] = [t].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Customers] AS [p.Customer.ProgramAccount] ON [p.Customer].[ProgramAccountId] = [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[Id]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [p.Customer.ProgramAccount.LocalityRep].*
    FROM [Security].[XQUsers] AS [p.Customer.ProgramAccount.LocalityRep]
    WHERE [p.Customer.ProgramAccount.LocalityRep].[Discriminator] = N'SALES_SP'
) AS [t0] ON [p.Customer.ProgramAccount].[LocalityRepId] = [t0].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [CustomerTypes] AS [p.Customer.CustomerType] ON [p.Customer].[CustomerTypeId] = [p.Customer.CustomerType].[Id]
WHERE ([p.UpdatedBy].[Discriminator] IN (N'INT_SYSADMMIN', N'XqInternalUser', N'EXT', N'SALES_SP', N'XqUser') AND [p.CreatedBy].[Discriminator] IN (N'INT_SYSADMMIN', N'XqInternalUser', N'EXT', N'SALES_SP', N'XqUser')) AND (EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [Security].[BusinessUserRegions] AS [r]
    WHERE [r].[RegionId] IN (CAST(6 AS bigint), CAST(8 AS bigint), CAST(9 AS bigint)) AND ([t].[Id] = [r].[BusinessUserId])) OR ([p.Customer].[ProgramAccountId] IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [Security].[BusinessUserRegions] AS [r0]
    WHERE [r0].[RegionId] IN (CAST(6 AS bigint), CAST(8 AS bigint), CAST(9 AS bigint)) AND ([t0].[Id] = [r0].[BusinessUserId]))))
ORDER BY [p].[CreatedOn]
```

It takes more than 30 seconds to execute and Azure SQL Server has query timeout of maximum 30 second, so it results in exception

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

From my layman's understanding about SQL I think SQL us fetching the entire dataset for sorting and then trying to do pagination and hence it's taking more than 30 seconds. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I need to sort the result in query in self otherwise it will not provide the desired result set.

Is their any way to deal with this situation.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `OrderBy(sortField)` is an unknown method.

Comment: It means you're missing an `INDEX` that would allow Azure SQL to efficiently sort your data. Please post the full generated T-SQL query that Linq generates.

Comment: Are your SQL tables properly indexed for your search? Try executing the query in SSMS, and check the estimated execution plan. Or better yet, the actual execution plan.

Comment: @SchmitzIT When running queries in SSMS it's important to ensure the `SET` options are the same, otherwise you'll run into every DBA's favourite problem: https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: What does `1.5L` mean?

Comment: @PeterB [L = Lakh = 100,000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh)

Comment: @Dai I thought of indexing, but as 1.5L records is not that big number, I just wanted to check on is there any other way to deal with it. I will update the question with generated SQL.

Comment: @SwapnilKumbhar 150,000 rows is definitely big enough to need indexing for effective querying. I'd say the _only_ time you can safely omit indexes is when all rows fit into a single [8KB page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide) - which implies an upper-bound of around ~160 rows (assuming an average row-size of 50 bytes), not _hundreds of thousands_ of rows.

Comment: I would recommend to not use an Indian-culture-only **`L`** designation on SO. Maybe you grew up with it, but I'm guessing most people here have never heard of it. Furthermore you say the query is fetching 150k records, but that could well be coming from *millions* of rows, making the need for indexing even bigger.